# What led to the cancellation of Kings?

Tags: kings

[**Kings**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1137462/) was a short run series that aired on NBC in the US that told, in a modern sense, the story of David from the bible.

The series seemed to have a sense of where it was going and aired a full season before being cancelled by NBC.

**Why**?

The initial reviews and ratings seemed to have a strong reaction to them and did not suffer from the same mistake Fox made with Firefly, airing episodes out of order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, [ratings](http://www.courthistorian.com/2009/07/the-new-king-part-2.php).  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings_%28U.S._TV_series%29#U.S._Nielsen_ratings) has a nice table of per-episode ratings.  After the premiere, the ratings plunged (Note that the first 4 episodes aired on Sundays.  After that, one episode aired on Saturday.  Then the rest was shelved until the summer).  After moving *Kings* off Sunday night, [NBC saw higher ratings in that timeslot](http://insidetv.ew.com/2009/04/13/ratings-nbc-bet/).

In addition, it was not cheap to make, at [$4 million an episode](http://www.tvweek.com/blogs/tvbizwire/2009/03/nbcs_silverman_backed_expensiv.php).  Personally, I think the show's poor marketing didn't help things.  Watching ads on TV leading up to the premiere didn't make it clear what *Kings* was or what it was about.  I only knew because I read up online about the show, and found the premise of 'bible story in the modern day' to be interesting.